# Error in using TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

```
<?php

require "twitteroauth-master/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumer_key = "xxx";
$consumer_secret = "xx";
$access_token = "xxx";
$access_token_secret = "xxx";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$access_token,$access_token_secret);
$tweets = $twitter->get(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?
    q=iphone&result_type=recent&count=20'
    );
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Twitter API SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php print_r($tweets); ?> 


</body>
</html>
```

All the keys and tokens are correct but I got the error below

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34 ) ) )
```

Anybody knows whats wrong in my code ? Thanks for your help in advance. I have tried to google the problem but dont seem to quite get it.

Comment: Why there's a linebreak in `tweets.json?    q`?

Comment: And that's probably the cause of the error too, @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on https://twitteroauth.com/, the correct format is this:

```
$tweets = $twitter->get(
    'search/tweets',
    array("q" => "iphone", "result_type" => "recent", "count" => 20)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Do you know how should I go about if I want to retrieve tweets that must contain two keywords that I want in a single tweet ? For example: iphone and samsung

Comment: @EFFWHYPEE: By default, if you want both keywords to appear in a tweet, you just need to do "iphone samsung". If you want to either the first or the second to appear in a tweet, it's "iphone OR samsung". Play around a bit with the [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en)